# Cite reference in latex in blue color

Tags: bibliographies, color, citing

In numeric citation call-outs, I want the `[` and `]` characters to be black and the number `12` in blue, please.

```
The debate on alternatives to null hypothesis significance tests based 
on p-values [63] has led to a renewed interest in the Bayesian alternative 
known as the Bayes factor. Advantages of such Bayesian tests include the 
ability to provide evidence in favor of both the null and the alternative 
hypotheses [12].

\item \label{Boscoe} 
{Boscoe, A., Paramore, C., & Verbalis, J. G. (2006). Cost of illness of 
hyponatremia in the United States. Cost effectiveness and resource 
allocation : C/E, 4, 10. https://doi.org/10.1186/1478-7547-4-10}
```

Comment: Please accept the provided answer if it solved the problem. If the problem is not solved then leave a comment and explain the remaining issue.

Answer (score 3):

I take it you build your document's bibliography by hand. If this assumption is correct, all you need to do to achieve your achieve is to (a) use `\bibitem` instead of `\item` in the `thebibliography` environment, (b) load the `cite` citation management package and use `\cite` commands to generate numeric-style citation call-outs, and (c) load the `hyperref` package and set the package option `citecolor=blue`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xurl} % to typeset URL strings
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}
\hyphenation{hypo-na-tremia} % optional
\begin{document}

\noindent
\cite{Boscoe}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\setcounter{enumiv}{11} % just for this example

\bibitem{Boscoe} Boscoe, A., Paramore, C., \& Verbalis, J. G. (2006). Cost 
of illness of hyponatremia in the United States. Cost Effectiveness and 
Resource Allocation: C/E, 4, 10. \url{https://doi.org/10.1186/1478-7547-4-10}

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```